# HttpSession Null with BlobstoreService

Tags: java, google-app-engine, httpsession

In my `Google App Engine` application, logged user can upload their picture with their other details. I have used `HttpSession` to manage logging. When logged user fills the form and selects a photo to upload and click on Save button, a `NullPointerException` is thrown because of `Session` is null. (Data is stored in database. but NullPointerException is thrown when trying to forward to success page after data is stored in database).

```
Form action = `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/users/adddetails")`
```

I have put `System.out.println(hs.getAttribute("logUserName") + "");` on top of the `servlet` which is trigger after click on Save button. output is `null`.

how can i avoid this ?

**UPDATED**

After logged user fills the form, goes to (`/users/adddetails`) path as i mentioned in my question and add data to database. it is working properly. after data added, redirects to another servlet using `resp.sendRedirect()` method. on that servlet i'm checking whether Session is null as below.

```
try 

{ 
  HttpSession hs = req.getSession();     

  if(!hs.getAttribute("logUserName").equals(null)) {
      RequestDispatcher d = req .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/userhome/add_data.jsp");
      d.forward(req, resp); }

  else { 
      RequestDispatcher d = req .getRequestDispatcher("user_login.jsp");
      d.forward(req, resp);
  }

} catch (NullPointerException ex) {

    // NullPointerException thrown from here

    RequestDispatcher d = req.getRequestDispatcher("user_login.jsp");
    d.forward(req, resp);
}catch (Exception ex) {
    RequestDispatcher d = req.getRequestDispatcher("/msg/exception.jsp");
    d.forward(req, resp);
}
```

`NullPointerException` is thrown from `catch` block in above code. `logUserName` is the parameter which i'm using from client to server to pass around the username.

Comment: Can you paste stack trace of the exception? Also is logUserName the parameter which you are using from client to server to pass around the user name? Some code of your actual operation where exception is thrown  would also be helpful!

Comment: It is absolutely unreadable. Can you edit original question and add code there

Comment: @vishal.biyani sorry. i'll edit original post

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code.

```
HttpSession hs = req.getSession(false);
if(hs == null)System.out.println("session is null");
else {
  String name = hs.getAttribute("logUserName");
  if(name == null)System.out.println("name is null");
  else System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable sessions ?
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling%5FSessions